# Ruby: map array of strings into array of arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, mapping

Let's assume I have an array which looks like this:

```
["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]
```

I want to replace each of these items of an array into an array adding the same value, like this:

```
[["aaa", 0], ["bbb", 0], ["ccc", 0]]
```

I don't understand why using:

```
arr_of_arr = arr.map{|single_item| single_item = [single_item, 0]}
```

does not work, but rather returns the following error:

```
 syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting '}'
```

Comment: It works for me. The error you are getting is somewhere else. Though you don't need the `single_item = ` part.

Comment: @ndn you were right in both cases, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

arr = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]

arr_of_arr = arr.map { |single_item| [single_item, 0] }

Answer (score 0):

As ndn pointed out, I can just write:

```
arr_of_arr = arr.map{|single_item| [single_item, 0]}
```

But my problem was somewhere else.